# Not able to edit giftlist name in ATG

Tags: jsp, atg

I'm trying to edit giftlist name. Below is my sample code.

```
<dsp:page>
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/commerce/gifts/GiftlistFormHandler" />
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach" />
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/dynamo/droplet/Switch"/>
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/userprofiling/Profile" var="profile"/>
<dsp:getvalueof param="operation" id="operation"/>
<dsp:droplet name="Switch">
    <dsp:param name="value" value="${operation}"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="edit">
        Wishlist name edited successfully.
    </dsp:oparam>
    <dsp:oparam name="error">
        Error while processing your request.
    </dsp:oparam>

 </dsp:droplet>
<dsp:droplet name="Switch">
<dsp:param name="value" bean="Profile.transient"/>
<dsp:oparam name="true">
  No profiles found
</dsp:oparam>
<dsp:oparam name="false">
  Giftlist list:
<dsp:form>
<dsp:select bean="GiftlistFormHandler.giftlistId" id="giftlistId">
<dsp:droplet name="ForEach">
    <dsp:param name="array" bean="Profile.giftlists"/>
    <dsp:param name="elementName" value="giftlist"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="output">
        <dsp:getvalueof var="giftList" param="giftlist"/>
        <dsp:getvalueof var="giftlistId" param="giftlist.id">
            <dsp:option paramvalue="${giftlist.id}">
                <dsp:valueof param="giftlist.id"/>
            </dsp:option>
        </dsp:getvalueof>
    </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
</dsp:select>
</dsp:form>
</dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#giftlistId").change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    $(".giftId").val(selectedText);
    });
});
</script>
<dsp:form name="editWishlistform">

        <label>WishList Name : </label>
        <dsp:input type="text" bean="GiftlistFormHandler.eventName"/>
        <br><input type="hidden" class="giftId" value=" " bean="GiftlistFormHandler.giftlistId"/></br>
        <dsp:input type="hidden" value="/test/mywishlist.jsp?operation=edit" bean="GiftlistFormHandler.updateGiftListSuccessURL"/>
        <dsp:input type="hidden" value="/test/mywishlist.jsp?operation=error" bean="GiftlistFormHandler.updateGiftListErrorURL"/>
        <dsp:input type="submit" value="Update" bean="GiftlistFormHandler.updateGiftList"/>
</dsp:form>
</dsp:page>
```

I've checked Profile.transient and displayed all giftlists in a drop down and also written script to get the selected value from drop down. Now, whatever giftlist id i'm selecting from the drop down it should be editable i mean i need to update giftlist name of that selected id. This is not happening i'm getting *Error while processing your request* message.
I've debugged the out of box handler method *handleUpdateGiftList()* there giftlistId is null. If anyone knows please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you stepped through your JavaScript and confirmed that it actually populates the hidden form field?

Comment: yes, i tried populating hidden value after ForEach droplet. It is displaying last giftlistId. But i want selected giftlistId to be populate. How to do this?